# Javascript Regex to replace any non-alphanumeric characters, including brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, velocity

I have this regex `/[\W_]+/g` that I use to remove any non-alphanumeric characters. However it does not remove brackets.

What I need is for it to remove any kind of bracket/paranthesis so that a string like `Hello (world)` becomes `helloworld`.

A string like `Hello(world)` becomes `helloworld`, but it does not work if there is a space between them.

Is this possible?

Comment: `"Hello (world)".replace(/[\W_]+/g, '')` works for me.

Comment: Are you using the `RegExp` constructor to create the regex by any chance?

Comment: Ok I'm using the regex also in Velocity Template and thats where it does not work. It is working in javascript. The syntax is a little different in VM.

Comment: I would recommend going with a whitelist approach rather than a blacklist, since you have a well-defined set of characters that you do want, not a set of ones that you don't. Something like `[^A-Za-z0-9]`

Comment: @CAustin that doesn't seem locale-friendly, as Megallion hasn't indicated these would only be ASCII or ANSI strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use this Java / JavaScript compliant regex according to RegexBuddy 4.x: 
`([\W\s_]+)`

And just replace anything it matches with `''` or `""`

Following the documentation [here](https://doc.dotcms.com/docs/latest/string-replace-regex), something like this:

```
#set($mystring = "Hello (world)! It's _{now}_ or -- [never]...;")
$mystring.replaceAll("</?([\W\s_]+)/?>", "");
```

=>

> `HelloworldItsnowornever`